# How to transpile vendor.bundle.js before its creation in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on an angular project where a specific node module is added as dependencies in package.json. While running the app using ng serve, I am getting syntax error on IE11 because the vendor.bundle.js is having some code which is not ES5. The added node module authors is not agreeing it to give the es5 version. So i decided can I transpile it in my project before generating vendor.bundle.js. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you are missing polyfills? What is your TSconfig set to target?

Comment: "target": "es5"

Comment: so the TS transpiler is suppose to handle this for you, basically already targeting correct JS, can you update your question with exactly what error you getting

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9508